# Unsupported file type: False warning in Odoo-10? how should I solve it? please tell me where I am making mess. Here's my code

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am trying to upload and import a csv file. When I chose file I'm getting warning/ error of file_type False. When Iam debugging the code I'm getting file content in binary, file_name also, but getting file_type field as false.

[this is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkiHa.png)

here is my .py code

```
file = fields.Binary(string='Input file')
file_type = fields.Char(string='Content Type', size=128)
file_name = fields.Char(string='File Name', size=128)
```

Here is the view code

```html
<group>
     <field name="file" filename="file_name"/>
     <field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
     <field name="file_type" invisible="True" attrs="{'readonly':[('file_type','!=', False)]}" />
     <field name="size" invisible="True" />
</group>
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should read below file:

**PY:**
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py,

**XML:**
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment_view.xml

Here you are doing wrong,

```
<field name="file_type" invisible="True" attrs="{'readonly':[('file_type','!=', False)]}" />
```

Comment: Where is it? in attrs attribute?

Comment: you should remove attrs .